# Change leaflet layer control icons

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

How can I change the icon for the Leaflet layers control icon in my webpage, when there are more than one such layers control?

The goal is to have *different* icons here:

[image: screenshot of two layers controls]

The code for that looks like:

```
var layers1 = L.control.layers(...).addTo(map);
var layers2 = L.control.layers(...).addTo(map);
```

If I change the control's icon via CSS, it changes in all layers controls.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this, however would be nice to see what you've done so far so we can just point you in the right direction.

Comment: this is my actual project 

http://80.211.9.217/webgis/


I would like to replace the icon of the second layer control

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found a much faster solution.
I simply overrided the `background-image` attribute of the specific Layer Control from the **styles.css** of my app in this way:

```
.leaflet-top.leaflet-right .leaflet-control-layers:nth-child(3) .leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
    background-image: /*set you value*/
}
```

In my case the second Layer Control was the third child (Toolbar, Layer Control 1 and Layer Control 2), so change that index to get the right Control. Hope it helps!

<Edit 2020: fixed typo in code>

Answer (score 4):

On one hand, I suggest you have a look at the [Leaflet list of plugins for layer switchers](https://leafletjs.com/plugins#layer-switching-controls). There might be one that fits your use case better than two default `L.Control.Layers` with different icons.

---

On the other hand: The layers control icon is supplied by CSS, in [this line](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/5161140e952969c5da27751b79154a2c93f53bfa/dist/leaflet.css#L346):

```
.leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
    background-image: url(images/layers.png);
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
}
```

That CSS class name comes from the [`_initLayout` private method](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/5161140e952969c5da27751b79154a2c93f53bfa/src/control/Control.Layers.js#L174) of `L.Control.Layers`:

```
_initLayout: function () {
    var className = 'leaflet-control-layers',
    // [snip]
    var link = this._layersLink = DomUtil.create('a', className + '-toggle', container);        
    // [snip]
}
```

Note how the toggler `HTMLElement`, which holds the image, is stored as a private property `this._layersLink`. That `HTMLElement` can be manipulated afterwards.

With this knowledge, we can [create a subclass of `L.Control.Layers`](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-3-controls.html),
like:

```
L.Control.Layers.TogglerIcon = L.Control.Layers.extend({
    options: {
        // Optional base CSS class name for the toggler element
        togglerClassName: undefined
    },

    _initLayout: function(){
        L.Control.Layers.prototype._initLayout.call(this);
        if (this.options.togglerClassName) {
            L.DomUtil.addClass(this._layersLink, togglerClassName);
        }
    }
});
```

And then create two of these layers controls passing that new option, e.g.:

```
var layers1 =
   new L.Control.Layers.TogglerIcon(..., ..., {togglerClassName: 'layers-flowers'});
var layers2 = 
   new L.Control.Layers.TogglerIcon(..., ..., {togglerClassName: 'layers-cars'});
```

And then have some CSS for their icons, e.g.:

```
.layers-flowers {
    background-image: url(images/layers-flowers.png);
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
}
.layers-cars {
    /* idem */
}
```

Please note that instead of adding a CSS class, one can also modify the `HTMLElement`'s inside the code, e.g.:

```
_initLayout: function(){
    L.Control.Layers.prototype._initLayout.call(this);
    if (this.options.backgroundImageUrl) {
        this._layersLink.style.backgroundImage = this.options.backgroundImageUrl;
    }
}
```

Albeit that might need a bit more precise fiddling.

Comment: I wrote a new question instead of commenting on your answer .. I'm sorry

Comment: Worked very well with your URL approach, apart from that you have to surround it by url(): 

this._layersLink.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + this.options.backgroundImageUrl + "')";