# Change Leaflet layer control icons on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have followed with great interest the post
[Change leaflet layer control icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50544217/change-leaflet-layer-control-icons/62791717#62791717) and implemented the advised code to change the icon of the Leaflet layers switch button. This works well on desktop browsers, see the images [collapsed layers switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC3iM.png) and [expanded layers switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgx6x.png.)

However, I have tested on quite a few browsers on different mobile devices and it is always the default Leaflet icon that appears on the layers switch, ([collapsed layers switch, mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7e99.png)). How can we change the icon also on mobile devices?

Comment: Does this happen on different mobile browsers too?

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a bit I came up with https://jsitor.com/WIM0PnQH2. It works for me on Android 9, on the Firefox and Chrome browsers.

I normally wouldn't recommend reaching this deep into Leaflet internal methods, but I don't see a cleaner way of implementing this. You would need to implement the CSS as well.

```js
var map = L.map("map").setView([19.04469, 72.9258], 12);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
var controllayer1 = L.control.layers({ map: map }, {}).addTo(map);

L.Control.Layers2 = L.Control.Layers.extend({
  _initLayout: function () {
    L.Control.Layers.prototype._initLayout.call(this);

    //replacing rather than overriding in case leaflet internal methods change in the future
    let ownclasses = this._layersLink.getAttribute('class');
    this._layersLink.setAttribute('class', ownclasses.replace('leaflet-control-layers-toggle', 'leaflet-control-layers-toggle-2'))

  }
});

L.control.layers2 = function (...args) {
  return new L.Control.Layers2(...args);
};

var controllayer2 = L.control.layers2({ map: map }, {}).addTo(map);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 80%;
}

.leaflet-bar a,
.leaflet-control-layers-toggle-2 {
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    }

.leaflet-control-layers-toggle-2 {
  background-image: url(https://mejrs.github.io/mejrs.github.io/images/favicon_skavid_map.png);
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}
//Should really be a higher detail version
.leaflet-retina .leaflet-control-layers-toggle-2 {
  background-image: url(https://mejrs.github.io/mejrs.github.io/images/favicon_skavid_map.png);
  background-size: 26px 26px;
}

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers-toggle-2 {
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
}

.leaflet-control-layers-expanded .leaflet-control-layers-toggle-2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The solution proposed by @kvothe works nicely. I tested it on Chrome and Safari on an old iphone (5S).